# What is an overview of resurrection events in the New Testament?

Tags: biblical-basis, resurrection

I was recently reading the account of Messiah's Passion in the Gospel of Matthew and read over this passage that I did not recall,

> Matthew 27:52-53 NASB The tombs were opened, and many bodies of the saints who had fallen asleep were raised; and coming out of the tombs after His resurrection they entered the holy city and appeared to many.

The passage stuck out to me for a few reasons:

- It is not synchronous with the immediate context of the narrative of Christ's passion and resurrection, since it appears at the point of the narrative before Jesus encounters Pilate.
- This resurrection event is not recalled in the other Gospels.
- The pre-millennial resurrection of Revelation 20 is called the "first resurrection".

I am curious to know how this relates to other resurrection events in the New Testament, especially events in which more than one person rises from the grave.

What is an overview of resurrection events in the New Testament?

Comment: You are asking for a hermeneutical answer, so why not ask on BH?

Comment: @Andrew if you are asking what they say, or how they connect, and/or how they are historically interpreted, then you are asking a hermeneutical question. If you are asking for historical church doctrine on this topic, then it is for here. But as your question is now it does not appears to be that, it appears to be a question of correlation of hermeneutics/interpretation.

Comment: @Joshua I have asked about a biblically-based overview of events. I do not believe that the question is too broad or off-topic now. I welcome further comments.

Comment: @Andrew The way I understand it, the overview of those events and how you understand what the event is or if it even applies to your criteria requires interpretation. So unless you are going to give a specific denomination or model of interpretation to give an overview for how **they** view the events the this becomes personal interpretation/truth/off topic for C.SE. That is how it has been represented to me and how I've seen it enforced. And maybe, even if it is on topic, I would personally suggest you may get a better answer at BHSE.

Comment: @Joshua I appreciate your comment. I think I'll leave the question as is for a few days before altering it again. I don't believe the question is a good fit for biblicalhermeneutics.SE- they will want me to ask about a specific verse or word.

Comment: Matthew 27:51-53 is the only such account in the New Testament.  I am not sure why you stated that it occurred before Jesus met Pilate, though, as this took place at the beginning of the same chapter.  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Dialogist I don't know how I confused that. Maybe I saw Pilate's name where the priests petition him to guard the tomb?

Comment: "How are they related" is *extremely* open-ended.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude edited

Answer (score 2):

For an overview of sorts, one could look to the [*Diatessaron of Tatian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatessaron).  It is an early harmony of the Gospels - written in Syriac, probably in the 2nd century - that was the basis for a respected Gospel commentary by Ephrem the Syrian.  [If I am not mistaken, the oldest Latin Gospel manuscripts in existence are in the form of a Diatessaron, but I might be recalling incorrectly.] The Resurrection accounts are in Sections 52 through 55, starting [here](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/100252.htm).  New Advent provides links to all of the actual Gospel verses indicated.

Another approach might be to consult the [*Eusebian Canons*](http://earlyenglishbibles.com/specialbibles/UseCanon.html), compiled in the early 4th century, which cross-reference Gospel passages to one another.  This is not an overview as requested, but could serve as a tool for creating one's own overview if the Diatessaron is found lacking.  The only online version of the Eusebian tables I am aware of is [here](http://www.bombaxo.com/euspage.html).